# Same MACRO definition , different output

Tags: c, macros, microcontroller

I have two projects, one from the microcontroller manufacturer and one from myself with a user generated makefile.

The following piece of code is perfectly working in the manufacturer's project, but in mine it throws the error: `error: expected identifier or '(' before '{' token`

```
#define EZRADIODRV_TRANSMIT_PLUGIN_INIT_DEFAULT                                \
{                                           /* Packet TX                   */  \
  NULL,                                     /* CallBack                    */  \
  {                                         /* Packet length config        */  \
    ezradiodrvTransmitLenghtDefault,        /* Default length mode         */  \
    0,                                      /* Packet length               */  \
    {0,0,0,0,0}                             /* Field lengths               */  \
  },                                                                           \
  RADIO_CONFIGURATION_DATA_CHANNEL_NUMBER,  /* Channel                     */  \
  ezradiodrvPacketTypeNormal,               /* Packet type                 */  \
  0,                                        /* Packet ID                   */  \
},

#else //#if defined( EZRADIO_PLUGIN_TRANSMIT )
#define EZRADIODRV_TRANSMIT_PLUGIN_INIT_DEFAULT
#endif  //#if defined( EZRADIO_PLUGIN_TRANSMIT )
```

Is there some sort of compiler flag I can set to omit this behaviour?

Comment: Check you don't have whitespace after the `'\'` at the end of the line  (do a hexdump if necessary, e.g. there could be a carriage-return character there that shouldn't be)

Comment: If the line endings are correct then you should get no error at all from this code since it is just preprocessor directives.  (If you mean that you get the error from a different code that uses this macro, then you need to post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))

Comment: you also might want to post the toolchain(s) you're using and produce preprocessed output for the area code code that produces the error (don't post the whole file of preprocessed output).  For gcc the "-E" option will produce preprocessor output.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I copied the file from the example build folder, that's where the error came from. I fixed it by using the original file from the SDK folder.